# Delete file using gradle task

Tags: gradle, scripting, task

I have this simple folder structure:

- build.gradle
- build\milestone\deployment\tool\tool.jar

I want to delete the tool.jar file using a gradle task. I tried:

```
task deleteRemainingJarAfterRename (type: Delete) {
delete 'tool.jar'
}
```

and called the task via

```
project.tasks.deploy.finalizedBy deleteRemainingJarAfterRename
```

but it didn't delete the file.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me,

```
task deleteRemainingJarAfterRename(type: Delete) {
        delete fileTree('build\milestone\deployment\tool\') {
            include '**/tool.jar'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why so complicated? You can simply pass the full path to the `delete` method: `delete 'build\milestone\deployment\tool\tool.jar'`